# ASP.NET MVC Areas: Can Someone Explain What's Happening PostBuild

Tags: asp.net-mvc, areas

I know to start using areas, you have to establish parent/child relationships.  I have a couple areas setup and their controllers are hitting just fine, the problem is some Views are not found.  I'm trying to gain an understanding of what's happening to my controllers that are not happening with my Views.

I'm very familiar with MSDN's link but I'm still having a disconnect:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total user error, I ended up creating a new area and forgot to uncomment the child area in the project code behind.  Sorry for the mislead!  Make sure to uncomment your parent and children area projects!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that maybe it is something to do with the routes.  Check to make sure you a registering all of your routes correctly (There's a couple extra things you need to account for when you are using Areas).

Phil Haack wrote a great [blog entry on Areas](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/31/single-project-areas.aspx), which may help with your problem.

**Edit:** Download the [ASP.NET MVC source](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en) and step through the code to see where it is breaking.  This should let you know exactly where the issue is.

Comment: I hit the correct controller fine via the routing so I don't think that is the problem.  The view the controller calls is not found.  I strongly believe it has to do with the post build exercise.

Comment: Try downloading the source for ASP.NET MVC and stepping through the code to see where it is breaking.  I'll edit the answer to post a link to the source.